# Can't get any input from mic jack connected to an electric guitar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, amplification

I recently bought an electric guitar and since i don't have an amp i use the instructions on instructables website on How to use your computer as a guitar amplifier and install guitar rig and the asio driver.

now my audio jack is a combo mic/headphone 3.5 jack.
when i connect my guitar to the jack i set it to mic but when i start the guitar rig software it only makes a noise and there seems to be no input from the mic jack in the sounds setting.

i'm on lenovo laptop with windows 10 installed

Comment: I think this is on topic, especially since the help center says "*electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, **except insofar as they interface with your computer***".

Answer (score 1):

If you tried following this instructable guide  [How to use your computer as a guitar amplifier by gilbert.vieux.9](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-your-computer-as-a-guitar-amplifier/?ALLSTEPS) then I think I know what your problem is.

You said your computer has one single combination jack that can be used for a speaker (headphone) output *and* a mic input, but it probably needs a special [headphone/microphone splitter like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006T65CXE)
[image: splitter]

to make it work with the plain microphone input adapter (¼inch to ⅛inch mono adapter) that the instructible guide says to use:

[image: adapter]

It's probably not touching the right input/mic contacts on your computer input - the orange splitter has 3 "black bars" so 4 contact areas, but the adapter only has 2 "black bars" so 3 contact areas -> mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

It makes a noise means the guitar is connected to the speaker, so check every physical cable connection to make sure that the plug is firmly inserted 100% into the socket, because if it is not plugged in properly, a steady noise may result.